# Microsoft 365 Learning SharePoint site keeps loading forever

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, learning

Inside our Office 365 tenant, we have provisioned the Office 365 Learning SharePoint site. But when users access the home page of the site or any other modern page inside the site, the web parts inside the page keeps loading forever as follow:-

[image]

Any advice what could be causing this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Which browser are you using? Have you tried clearing your cache?

Comment: @CallumCrowley tried this on chrome, edge & Firefox + yes i cleared the browser cache.. nothing solved this issue

Answer (score 0):

There may have been a problem when provisioning the site, causing a problem with this page. You could try editing and then re-publishing the page, to see if it resolves the problem.

If this does not work, I would recommend opening a ticket with Microsoft as this is out-of-the-box functionality which is outside of the control of end users.

You can create a new service request via the Microsoft 365 admin portal. In the menu section, you'll see the "New service request" option within "Support".

Comment: the site use to work well.. i tried to edit and republish but it did not work either.

Comment: If you have previously made changes to the page, you could try to restore an earlier version of the page via site pages (using version history).

Comment: If this response answered your question, please do mark it as the answer or upvote the response. This helps ensure that questions and responses are useful to the wider community.